# SQL increment between a range without duplicates - multithreaded

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'll try to provide as much detail as I can on this. What is the best way to increment between a range of numbers in a high transaction environment, meaning, calls come in very fast from a web api?

The first table I have is a master table of the ranges that are available to use. It's noted below. I'm not quote sure if this is the best way to implement it either, so I'm open to suggestions

Company A initially gave me a range of 100-200. Over time, we started to run low so they gave us a new range. The new range is 201-300.

```
Company   Range    Inactive
   A      100-200      X
   B      100-200
   C      200-350
   A      201-300
```

The second table is the list of numbers that have been used between the ranges.

```
 Company  Number    DateUsed
   A      198       2017-11-30
   B      199       2017-11-30
   A      200       2017-11-30
   B      105       2017-11-30
   C      215       2017-11-30
   A      201       2017-11-30
```

Once a range is used up, I need to be able to flag out that range so it's not used anymore, and use the next range that's available. I was thinking of adding a "Last Used" number to the first table and doing an Update statement with an output with a case statement on inactive flagging it inactive if its empty.

The question I have is what is the best way to do this in a high transaction environment? I'm familiar with `Scope_Identity`, but I don't think this will work in this setup.

Comment: Are you able to break the range column out into two columns? For instance, `RangeLow` and `RangeHigh`. If so then it would make this problem easier. It would also make your table more "atomic", a key feature in properly structuring a relational database.

Comment: Yes, splitting out the range wouldn’t be a prob. That’s how I would do it normally. This was just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Having an inactive flag in the first table seems perfectly sane to me. I've written and tested a query that will update your flag, provided the Range column is split into a lower range column and upper range column. I'm calling the tables `Ranges` and `RangeLog` respectively.

```
UPDATE Ranges
SET Inactive = 'X'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT tA.Company, RangeLow, RangeHigh, COUNT(*)
              FROM Ranges tA INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Company, Number 
                                         FROM RangeLog) tB ON tA.Company = tB.Company AND (Number BETWEEN tA.RangeLow AND tA.RangeHigh)
              GROUP BY tA.Company, RangeLow, RangeHigh
              HAVING RangeHigh - RangeLow + 1 = COUNT(*)
                     AND Ranges.Company = tA.Company AND Ranges.RangeLow = tA.RangeLow AND Ranges.RangeHigh = tA.RangeHigh)
```

Obviously this won't work with the schema the way you have it now, but making the split to the Range lookup column makes the data more atomic and usable, and easier to write queries. And it's a fairly minor modification to your table.

Let us know how this looks to you!